# Creating Hive View - Turn off metadata lookup from Hive Metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive, view, hiveddl

Is it possible to create a hive view on top of a nonexistent hive table or views?. This ability will help us deploy the hive DDL without any order at the time of refresh (migrating tables or views from one environment to another). In our environment, we have views built on top of another view. If we deploy them in any order, with the default setup some of the views may fail saying the underlying table/view doesn't exist. Looking to see if we can turn off the metadata lookup from hive metastore so that the type checks are not done at the time of view creation. It can be enforced after the deployment or at the time of querying the view for data retrieval because by that time all the views/tables will be completely deployed and there won't be any type checking related errors.

I checked on the internet for pointers but I couldn't find any. Any suggestions in this regard will be helpful to us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add IF NOT EXISTS to all create statements and run all several times until errors disappear.

If executed 2 times in the wrong order like this, second run will succeed without any error:

```
drop view if exists my_view;
create view if not exists my_view as select from table1; --fails first time, succeeds on second run
drop table if exists table1;
create table if not exists table1(id int);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this trick but by doing this I will not be able to differentiate between failure due to dependency or syntax issue. And also depending on how many views we have, we might have to run several times (not able to know how many times in advance)

Comment: @VenkatesanMuniappan Yes, you are right, many runs may be needed and not possible to understand when to stop. This is why much better to have install script which calls other files in order. It is not possible to disable view script validation

Comment: Ok @leftjoin. Is there any easy way to do topological sorting on the list of views based on their dependency?. If we know that then we can follow this order and be rest assured.

Comment: @VenkatesanMuniappan There is a Jira to enable dependency tracking in the metastore, vote for it and maybe they will implement it,

Comment: Sure thing @leftjoin. Let me find the associated hive story and will upvote it.

Comment: @VenkatesanMuniappan https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1077 AND THIS HIVE-1073

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find only https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1073 through my search on the JIRA. Thanks for the other one. This HIVE-1077 depends on HIVE-1073. I have upvoted both. Not sure if that will get any attention since this story was created about 10 years ago :D.